# Replacing a relative URL with an absolute URL without using HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess

I have the following relative URL (my website is www.web1.com).

```
<a href="/28518/verona-torino" target="partidos"> View! </a>
```

I need another URL (**not** www.web1.com) inserted here, either from JavaScript, PHP, or .htaccess.

The code should be as follows:

```
<a href="http://www.web2.com/28518/verona-torino" target="partidos"> View! </a>
```

Editing the HTML manually is not an option.

Comment: Is the `http://www.web2.com` the same website that the link is on?

Comment: Well you could use .attr('href') to get the old url, add the old url after the absolute url you want and put it back in to the anchor.

Comment: This depends on what you are looking to do. Do you want the domain to be in the source code or just when you click.

Comment: The url I want to open is in http://www.web2.com, and the code is in http://www.web1.com

Comment: If "edit the code manually is not a solution" then how is PHP an option at all?

Comment: Are we dealing with plain html files? Or are you already using PHP to generate the website? Do you have other relative url that shouldn't be changed to the other domain? Or could you just use `<base href="http://www.web2.com/" />`?

Comment: Same thing if you encuantra in source code or when I click

Comment: SOLVED! Use <base href="http://www.web2.com/" />. Thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

**Top of all PHP files**

```
<?php
define('URL', 'http://www.web2.com/');
?>
```

**In HTML you can now do this**

```
<a href="<?php echo URL; ?>28518/verona-torino" target="partidos"> View! </a>
```

Comment: SOLVED! Use <base href="web2.com/"; />. Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

If you use jquery library, this may help:

```
$.each('a', function() {
  var t = $(this).attr('href');
  $(this).attr('href', 'http://www.web2.com'+t);
});
```

Be aware that it's not SEO friendly way.